# VB.Net Array Of Controls

Tags: arrays, vb.net, controls

I've created a program where I have various UserControls which I have created.

On my main form, I have a button which, when first pressed, creates an array of all the controls in the form.
After this, it adds controls, removes controls, changes properties etc.. but the array is not touched again until just before the end of the Button_Click sub.

At this point, depending on the result of a check I've put in at the end, I want all the controls to be removed, and then all the controls from the array re-adding to the form.

I can do this easily enough, but when I add the controls from the contents of the array, it adds them with properties from after I initially created the array.

For example,
My form has Button1, Button2 and Button3.
On the click event of Button1, an array called Controls() is created

```
    Dim _Controls() as Control
    Dim _Index as Long = -1

    For Each Ctl as Control In Me.Controls
        _Index += 1
        _Controls(_Index) = Ctl
    Next Ctl
```

After this is created, I programmatically add several other controls (Button4, Button5 and Button6 as an example), I change the text and locations of Button2 and Button3, and then perform a check which returns a Boolean.

If the Boolean is true, I exit the sub, if false then I want to revert everything back the way it was using the array I created.

```
    If _Check Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each Ctl As Control In Me.Controls
            _OldIndex += 1
            _OldControls(_OldIndex) = Ctl
        Next Ctl

        For Each Ctl As Control In _OldControls
            Me.Controls.Remove(Ctl)
        Next Ctl

        For Each Ctl As Control In _Controls
            Me.Controls.Add(Ctl)
        Next Ctl
    End If
```

This works successfully at adding all the original controls (in our example, Button1, Button2 and Button3) but the properties are that of the controls after I've made all the changes.
So, with our example, Button1 is added in the correct place, Button2 and Button3 are added in the new location.

Can anyone tell me how I can create an array of controls, but let it keep all the properties at the time it is created rather than allow them to change?

I hope I've explained this well enough.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Controls are objects, when you add them to your array you are not adding a copy or clone, but a reference to an existing one.  After you remove them from the Form, your array still holds onto a reference to them.  So, the next time around, you start where you left off property-wise.  Whatever you are doing could very well leak resources as well.

Comment: It seems that you are making an array with the **reference** of the Controls. Try to wrap your copy statement in a Sub and pass the Controls to copy `ByVal` as paramaters

Comment: Controls cannot be copied.  You should be considering two UserControls, just swap them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are doing but you could store the controls in a panel and just show/hide the panels that are needed.

Comment: Those also do not seem to be `UserControls` *per se* but standard ordinary WinForms controls.

Comment: Plutonix and Yerko Palma, I'd realised it was just a reference, but I want to have the array be actual controls (if possible.)
Hans Passant, I'm not trying to copy the control, just create new ones that have the same properties.
the_lotus, the controls are created at runtime so panels wouldn't work.
Plutonix, I'm aware they're standard controls, I was using them as examples.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you aren't doing the check first and then only modifying the controls if needed? If you can do that then, problem solved by avoidance?

Comment: @SteMoore - Panels are just controls.  If you can add your other controls at runtime you can add a panel too.  In fact if you create a custom panel class that inherits panel and load it with the controls set to initial values, simply remove the panel you're done with and add a new custom panel.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I was dragged away from the project for a while. 
The reason for all this is that I've made my own DataGridView with an extra property of CanMoveCells.
When this is true, instead of selecting cells when you click and drag, it grabs one cell and moves it with your mouse like a drag drop and on mouse up, the cell gets placed at the new location, and any cells before it on the same row move down one.

Comment: I've done this by, on mouse down, creating a picturebox with the image of the cell as it currently is and sets the origin cell to have the same forecolor and backcolor as the datagridview backgroundcolor. On mouse move, I move the picturebox. 
Then on mouse up, I create pictureboxes of the other cells in the location they currently are, and to the left of the origin cell stay in the same place.

Comment: Any to the right of the origin cell, and to the left of where my moved picturebox currently is, get moved to the left until they are in the same location as the cells should be, and then all the cells to the right of my moved cell stay where they are.
On the mousedown event, I create an array to hold all the current cell details of every cell in the row, but when I change the cells, the array changes too as it is just a reference.

Comment: I need a way to keep the details that the array holds, even after changing the cell. Can anyone help? I've tried what Yerko Palma has suggested and it still works the same and the reason I can't do the check first is because it all happens in realtime.

Comment: This is a lot different than when I first asked the question, as I no longer create a usercontrol to mimic the cell and just populate an array and show a picturebox instead.
However, the issue where arrays are being updated due to its reference to the original cell, still exists.